# What is going on in this piece of c++ code? (Resolution operator with inheritance ?!?)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, scope

I don't know what is going on in this piece of code. this is from a working piece of code that I have to understand.

```
orange::orange():
  hello_short(false),
  hello_long(false),
  foo(NULL),
  foo2(NULL),
  quiet(false)
{
  res  = NULL;
  good = true;
}
```

Comment: For the weird colon after the constructor's name, see [this FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
orange::orange():
```

simplies says that you are defining a function of the class orange (the left part), the function is called "orange" (the right part) and takes no arguments. Since the function is named the same as the class and returns no value, it's aconstructor of your class

The rest is an initialisation list : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Answer (score 1):

It initializes the class members with the given values (`hello_short` will be `false`, `hello_long` will be `false`, `foo` will be `NULL`, etc), sets `res` to `NULL` and sets `good` to `true`.

The initialization list is always done *before* executing the constructor (i.e. the code within the curly braces).

Also, there is a syntax error: after `foo2(NULL)`, a comma should come.